# incorrect variable value after bit shift and addition in c

Tags: c

I have this code which basically takes two integers and shifts each and adds them. However, after the addition I got an incorrect value.

I have found a way out of this (that is by storing the shifted values in new unsigned int variables and adding the two) but I want to understand why this one did not work:

```
void change(uint8_t in[3], uint16_t out[2]){
    out[0] = in[0]<<2 + in[1]>>2;
    printf("%u\n",in[0]<<2 ); // outputs 48  --- correct
    printf("%u\n",in[1]>>2 ); // output 1 --- correct
    printf("%u\n",out[0] ); // output 768 --- wrong, I expected 49
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    uint8_t in[3] = {12,6,9};
    uint16_t out[2];
    change(in,out);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use brackets `out[0] = (in[0]<<2) + (in[1]>>2);`

Comment: `puts("hello, operator precedence");`

Comment: @Vaibhav , that solved my problem. thanks very very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operator `+` has [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than shift operators. You need to write:

```
out[0] = (in[0]<<2) + (in[1]>>2);
```

Without parentheses it's been evaluated as

```
out[0] = in[0] << (2 + in[1]) >> 2;
```

GCC shows this warning upon compiling your code with warnings on:

```
test.c:5:23: warning: suggest parentheses around ‘+’ inside ‘<<’ [-Wparentheses]
     out[0] = in[0]<<2 + in[1]>>2;
                       ^
```

This is an example of why we should always pay attention to compiler warnings.

Comment: @Babydesta that is warning, not error. Please check your compiler's documentation on how to turn on warnings. For GCC I always use `-Wall -Wextra`.